# Kinect openCV openNI not working

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, openni

I'm trying to use kinect with **OpenNI**, when I try to build any program, it does not give any build errors but I get these errors on the command line

```
CvCapture_OpenNI::readCameraParams : Could not read property "ShadowValue"!
CvCapture_OpenNI::CvCaptureOpenNI: Could not read camera paramerers
done.
Can not open a capture object.
```

I tried to build (kinect_maps.cpp) provided with OpenCV, still gives the same error.

I am using Kinect for Windows on Windows 7 64 bit.

Many thanks.

Comment: Update your OpenNI drivers to the latest version.

Comment: can you run the samples that come with openni ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on the 64bit version on windows. I fixed them uninstalling the 64bit version and installing the 32bit version. You will also need to install the Nite and the sensor driver for 32bits.